# Cron Error Job was running longer than the configured max_running_time

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.6

In cron_schedule table I see the cron job "execute_tasks" always ends with an error stating "Job was running longer than the configured max_running_time". I know this happens when the cron job runs longer than the setting "Missed if Not Run Within" which I have set to 120 minutes. Why does the "execute_tasks" job end with an error? 2 hours seems like plenty of time. We have the cron.php set to run every 1 minute.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, I don't recall an `execute_tasks` cron job in Magento. Is this some sort of custom cron job in your project? Perhaps it's part of a module? It's typically unusual for a cron job to run for so long, especially since it could block other cron jobs from running (unless they're set to run on the `always` schedule). Do you know what this cron job is doing?

Answer (score 2):

This message may appear if you installed Magento module "AOE Scheduler".

This means that your php value of "max_execution_time" has a low value, you'll need to ask to your host provider to increment this value.

Also you may try make bigger value of "memory_limit".